# How to get value of textField in UITableViewCell into textFieldDelegate Method shouldChangeCharactersIn?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, cell

I have a tableViewCell With textFields. I want to get a value for individual textField when character change in textfields. so how can i get txtfield value for all textfields

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


    var arrChanged : NSMutableArray = []


    for i in 0..<arrCheckList.count{
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        let cell: CheckInCell = tblViewCheckIn.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CheckInCell

        if(textField.text?.count != 0){
            let dictData = (arrCheckList.object(at: cell.txtQty.tag) as! NSDictionary).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableDictionary
            dictData.setValue(cell.txtQty.text, forKey: "check_list_qty")

            arrChanged.add(dictData)
        }

    }

    arrCheckList = arrChanged

    return true
}
```

Comment: You can use closures and delegates to send text from tablecell to your controller.... you just need to define textfield delegates in Uitableviewcell and write the closure and delegate call action in shouldchangecharacters delegate. you can differentiate different textfield using tag so that you can identify the particular textfield.

Comment: can you please define with code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code to get the complete text in text field inside should change characters:

```
 var str:NSString = textField.text! as NSString
 str = str.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
```

For getting particular text field, you can set tag in cell for row and here you can check the text field tag to identify Text field.

In cell for row set:

```
    cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then in should change characters in range

```
  array[textfield.tag] = str //which is the textfieldvalue
```

So here you can store text field value as per tableview row index.

Comment: how i can check the text field tag to identify Text field. Please describe with code??

Comment: Share the code of cell for row how many text fields you have in one cell?

Comment: I have Only One TextField

Comment: but in my case change the number of rows when change the array count. so how much cases i add??

Comment: Ok I have edited it more as per your case. But if it does not solve problem please edit your question more what exactly you want?

Comment: ThankYou So Much For Helping Me...I Got Idea What I Want to Do Actually So I Solved It...:)